# Edges of bins with 1 element in multi dimensional histogram

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm attempting to downsample an D-dimensional array of points (D>1). The steps are as follow:

1. Generate the D-dimensional histogram
2. Clip at a maximum value of 1
3. Retrieve the position of those bins where N=1

The idea is to go from the distribution of points shown on the left, to the one shown on the right (in 2D here for visualization):

[image]

The first two points are easy, but I'm struggling to find a **fast** (this is important) way to solve the 3rd point. That is: from the clipped histogram, how do I retrieve (as fast as possible) the edge coordinates associated to those D-dimensional (clipped) bins with 1 element inside?

---

```
import numpy as np

N, D = 500, 3

# Random D-dimensional distribution of N points
arr = np.random.uniform(0., 10., (N, D))

# Some random number of bins
bins = np.random.randint(20, 40, D)
# D-dimensional histogram
hst, edges = np.histogramdd(arr, bins=bins)
# Clip at max=1
hst = np.clip(hst, a_min=None, a_max=1)

# This block below needs to be as fast as possible
# Find bins where there is 1 element
idxs = np.array(np.where(hst > 0)).T
# Extract coordinates
hst_dwnsmp = []
for pt in idxs:
    coord = []
    for i, j in enumerate(pt):
        coord.append(edges[i][j])
    hst_dwnsmp.append(coord)
```